# How to maintain state of the component while navigating in react native

Tags: react-native, state

Suppose I have two scenes or pages in react native.In first page,i have two buttons, i have one state variable whose value is initially set to false but when user click on first button that state variable value is change to 'true'.Then when user clicks on second button ,user gets navigated to second scene.After some interaction on second page or scene user again navigate to first page.When user navigate to first page state variable which was set to true again reset to false as page renders again. How should i maintain the state of variable and how to stop it from resetting to original value?????

Answer (score -1):

You should probably look into a state management system like Redux.